# XSLT 1.0 - Unexpected token '{' in the expression. -->{<-- name(.)}

Tags: xslt-1.0, biztalk, biztalk-2016

Given the input file shown below, the first code example works, and the second code example fails with error:

> Unexpected token '{' in the expression.   -->{<-- name(.)}

The main difference is whether I put the `{name(.)}` in a name attribute or a select attribute.  I need to generate the data like the second code to match my OAGIS ProcessShipment schema.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//s0:B2">
       <xsl:for-each select="./*">
            <xsl:if test=".">
                <xsl:element name="{name(.)}" > 
                   <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
                </xsl:element> 
            </xsl:if>

       </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

The code that fails:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//s0:B2">
       <xsl:for-each select="./*">
            <xsl:if test=".">
                <xsl:element name="ID" xmlns="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/10">
                    <xsl:attribute name="typeCode">
                        <xsl:value-of select="{name(.)}" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

Desired Output:

```
  <ID typeCode="B202>ABCD</ID>
  <ID typeCode="B204>0080082626</ID>
  <ID typeCode="B206>PP</ID>
```

Input data:

```
<ns0:X12_00401_204 xmlns:ns0="http://example.com/X12/204">
    <ST>
        <ST01>204</ST01>
        <ST02>0001</ST02>
    </ST>
    <ns0:B2>
        <B202>ABCD</B202>
        <B204>0080082626</B204>
        <B206>PP</B206>
    </ns0:B2>
</ns0:X12>
```

Reference: [How to select each child node of a parent in a for-each xslt statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919463/how-to-select-each-child-node-of-a-parent-in-a-for-each-xslt-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By trial and error I got this to work:

```
<xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />
```

Just removed the curly braces, which tell it to run what is inside as braces as xpath. I'm still a little fuzzy why it is needed in the name= though.

Comment: Because the `name` attribute of `xsl:element ` is interpreted as an [attribute value template](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#dt-attribute-value-template), while the `select` attribute of `xsl:value-of` is an [expression](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#dt-expression).

Comment: Don't forget to mark your own answer as the answer that solved your issue.